# PHP repeat with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I already can get my data from database, and I need to show it using checkbox. I'm not sure what is wrong, I need it to repeat only once, with 2 checked box, but for now it repeat twice. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$edit_data->service_day = "목,토";
$service_day = explode(',', $edit_data->service_day);
foreach($service_day as $row){
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_1" value="월" 
<?php   if($row == "월"){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_1">월</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_2" value="화"
<?php if($row == "화"){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_2">화</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_3" value="수"
<?php if($row == "수"){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_3">수</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_4" value="목"
<?php if($row == "목"){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_4">목</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_5" value="금"
<?php if($row == "금"){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_5">금</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_6" value="토"
<?php if($row == "토"){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_6">토</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_7" value="일"
<?php if($row == "일"){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_7">일</label>
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [`explode`](http://php.net/explode)-ing the services, thus making it an array.

[`Foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is iterating through the array (in your example it has two elements), therefore the code in the body of that foreach is going to repeat twice. If you have 3 elements, it is going to be repeated three times. And so on.

One way to achieve what you are after is to use [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) to check if the service is in the array you have. If it is in the array, mark the checkbox as `checked`.

```
<?php
$edit_data->service_day = "목,토";
$service_day = explode(',', $edit_data->service_day);
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_1" value="월" 
<?php   if(in_array("월", $service_day)){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_1">월</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_2" value="화"
<?php if(in_array("화", $service_day)){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_2">화</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_3" value="수"
<?php if(in_array("수", $service_day)){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_3">수</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_4" value="목"
<?php if(in_array("목", $service_day)){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_4">목</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_5" value="금"
<?php if(in_array("금", $service_day)){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_5">금</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_6" value="토"
<?php if(in_array("토", $service_day)){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_6">토</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_7" value="일"
<?php if(in_array("일", $service_day)){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
>
<label for="checkbox2_7">일</label>
</td>
```

Another approach is:

```
<?php 

//All of the available service days
$available_service_days = ['월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토', '일'];

//Checked service days
$edit_data->service_day = "목,토";
$service_day = explode(',', $edit_data->service_day);


//Loop through the available service days to generate checkbox
foreach($available_service_days as $key => $available_service_day) {
//Print the checkbox and check it if necessary
?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="service_day[]" id="checkbox2_<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $available_service_day; ?>" 
    <?php if(in_array($available_service_day, $service_day)){echo 'checked="checked"';}?>
    >
    <label for="checkbox2_7"><?php echo $available_service_day; ?></label>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: ah i see, Thank you so much! i already tried using in_array, but i think i use the wrong data lol

Comment: @beginnerprogrammer I updated my answer with another approach, which in my opinion is better. Also you have tagged your question with [tag:laravel] & if that is your code in a `view` you should use [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade). Best of luck!

Comment: Yeah, it looks good and Thanks for all the comment in that code! Have a nice day